# Rmarkdown - python inline code in Rmarkdown

Tags: r-markdown, reticulate

I am using Rmarkdown with python. What is the equivalent of the `R` inline code for python?
Example, in https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/lesson-4.html I can do

> ``r x`

to display the value of x in the text. but If I do

> ``python x`

I just get the text `python x`

Comment: that's what I went with! can you add it so i can accept?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure whether this is possible. All examples I have found use R inline code like so `r py$x` to achieve that. See e.g. the [rmarkdown cookbook](http://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/eng-python.html).

Answer (score 4):

With this workaround, it's possible:

````
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(reticulate)
```
 
```{python include=FALSE}
result = 1 + 1
```
 
1 + 1 = `r py$result`    # 1 + 1 = 2
````

Where `py$result` means: take the value of the Python variable called `result`.