# knitr - inline code chunk of foreign engine

Tags: r, knitr

I've written a knitr engine to process Maxima code (as part of a [package](https://github.com/rcst/rim)), which works for "regular" chunks just fine, e.g.:

````
```{maxima}
1+1;
```
````

results in

```
(%i1) 1+1;
```

```
# (%o1) 2
```

However, when I try to get the output printed inline, such as

```
`maxima 1+1;`
```

It gets printed literally: `maxima 1+1;`

The *R Markdown Cookbook* explicitly says

> inline: processing output from inline R expressions.

So I guess this is not meant be working (yet), but I wanted to ask here if there is a way to do this/ workaround before filing a feature request at github.

Comment: All I could find suggests that inline chunks are always evaluated in `R`. You would have to provide a wrapper function to call `maxima` from `R` as it is done for e.g., Python. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/65344688/5028841. But I might be wrong...

Comment: Ah it seems you already did! So this would be a sensible workaround: r rim::maxima.get("1+1;")`. However, I see that it would be good to know if this is the only way and maybe also why.

Comment: That would be one way, indeed. However, `rim::maxima.get()` uses a different Maxima session than the knitr engine. Thus you wouldn’t be able to use previous inputs and results.