# How can I use display Markdown in a qmd file?

Tags: markdown, inline, display, quarto

I am aksing myself how I can use display Markdown in a qmd file corretly. I have this code:

````
```{python}
#| echo: true

# Pandas laden
import pandas as pd 

# csv Datei über read_csv laden
file = "Priorisierung_der_Anforderungen.csv"
df = pd.read_csv(file)
Anzahl_Karten = str(len(df))

from IPython.display import display, Markdown

display(Markdown("""
# Lesen der Daten

Im Anforderungsworkshop wurden insgesamt {Anzahl_Karten} Anforderungskarten der Teilnehmenden in einer Excel Tabelle erfasst.
""")).format(Anzahl_Karten)

```
````

I want to include the variable 'Anzhal_Karten' in the text. I understand that I need to use display, Markdown for this.

But I receive thids error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'format'
```

And my output looks like this:

```
Lesen der Daten
Im Anforderungsworkshop wurden insgesamt {Anzahl_Karten} Anforderungskarten der Teilnehmenden in einer Excel Tabelle erfasst.
```

Thank you for any tips.
Sebastian

Comment: Maybe this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65344130/rmarkdown-python-inline-code-in-rmarkdown/69622352#69622352) is useful for you. See also this [discussion](https://github.com/quarto-dev/quarto-cli/discussions/3570).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are receiving the error `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'format'` becuase you are using the string [`format`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) method on [`display`](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/generated/IPython.display.html#IPython.display.display). And `display` returns `None` if no `display_id` is given (default). But *NoneType* has no `format` method or attribute. Hence the error.

So you need to format the string inside the `Markdown` function. And I would suggest using f-string (introduced in *python 3.6*, read the [PEP 498](https://peps.python.org/pep-0498/))

````
---
title: Display Markdown
format: html
jupyter: python3
---

```{python}
#| echo: true

# Pandas laden
import pandas as pd 

# csv Datei über read_csv laden
file = "Priorisierung_der_Anforderungen.csv"
df = pd.read_csv(file)
Anzahl_Karten = str(len(df))

from IPython.display import display, Markdown

display(Markdown(f"""
# Lesen der Daten

Im Anforderungsworkshop wurden insgesamt {Anzahl_Karten} Anforderungskarten der Teilnehmenden in einer Excel Tabelle erfasst.
"""))

```
````

[image: f-string in Markdown]

---